# Get value of checked radio input and check it with php

Tags: php, forms, if-statement, radio-button

I am trying to write a function that has an if condition to first see which option of an input is checked and then to check that value.  For example, in the code below, I have a radio input named "term_id".  I want to first get the option that is checked and then check the value.  And then if that value is 70, for example, then do something. I also want to accomplish this with php if possible and not jquery.

```
 $terms = get_terms( 'heythere', $args );
            if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
                echo '<ul class="form-ul">';
                $count = 0;
 foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    $count++;
                    $t_id = $term->term_id;
                    $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" );
                    ?>
  <li>
                        <label>
                          <input type="radio" name="term_id" value="<? php echo $term->term_id; ?>" <?php if ($count == 1) { echo 'checked="checked"';  } ?>>
                       </label>

  </li>
```

I a very new to php and this is my go at it but I am sure it is incorrect.

```
if(isset($_GET[term_id]) && ($term->term_id === '70')) {
 DO THIS
 }
```

Comment: Since you are not doing your check inside your `foreach ( $terms as $term )`, then the `$term->term_id` is out of scope. Your check could be a simple `if(isset($_GET['term_id']) && ($_GET['term_id'] === '70')) { DO THIS }`

Comment: Got it.  Thank you!